# How to increase the input length of a neural network?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, deeplearning4j

I have a neural network with an input of size n and I want to extend it to a network with an input of size n + m with m > 0. How?

More details:
I am training a classifier that gets as input the probability distribution of an instance and outputs a binary value. For example let's say each instance in my dataset can have 10 different labels (For example MNIST), I have the probability distributions of all the instances. Let's say I want to classify these instances as Good/Bad. Let's say I have trained a model on one dataset (MNIST) and now I want to expand it to another dataset like cifar-100, in which every instance could have 100 different labels. I want to design a model (Neural Network) that could be trained on one dataset and trained on another dataset.
For example, people trained AlexNet on ImageNet and finetune it on another dataset by removing the last layer, and adding another layer with different size.
How could I do similar thing when the constraint is on the input not the output of the network? Is it possible to design a network that could have a variable length input? Or is it possible to change maybe 1,2 layers and finetune the network on another dataset?
[Is the problem clear? :)]

Answer (score 0):

You could resize your images in CIFAR-100(32x32) using Opencv or PIL to bring them to the size of MNIST (28x28), and do an unsupervised fine-tuning on the images using Deep Belief Networks.